# How can I release RAM that is used by the database after database work finished?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How can I release RAM that is used by the database after database work finished? (the RAM usage is 1.57 before running SP and after that, SP running and finished, RAM usage is 2.24 - when restart [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) it's will be OK).

We have just one multi-purpose server. This server is SQL Server Host, and we also run other enterprise applications on this server, and these applications need free RAM space too.

How can I ensure these applications have enough RAM to run?

Comment: Why would you need to? A database server should use as much memory that is available, if it is to do its job properly.

Comment: after database work finished!ram must be released! but it dosen't happen

Comment: becasue we have several SPs which execute consequncely , and each SP take a lot of memory because of its operations (like UNION) ... so we have to set MINIMUM & MAXIMUM SERVER MEMORY option in server properties...
we expect that SQL server should release these information from RAM because we don't need them after our application closed ...
in other word , we need to return memory taken by SQL to OS after closing our application .

Comment: But why? What else on this server uses RAM except for the database? Let the database manage its own memory - it knows what RAM it can reuse.

Comment: Because we have just one multi-purpose server , this server is SQL server Host and for some reason we should run other Enterprise applications on this server, and these applications need free RAM space too...

Comment: **we have just one multi-purpose server** - that's the missing piece from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had such a problem before, and I found a solution for this issue.
You can create a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) as described below:
Before you start your application, you should call this stored procedure in Mode 1, because you need sufficient memory.

For SQL operations and before closing your application, you have to call this stored procedure again in Mode 0:

```
Create Proc  [dbo].[MP_Rpt_ConfigureMemory]
(  @Mode  bit  )
as
declare @RAM as integer
declare @MAX as integer
declare @MIN as integer

set @RAM =
(SELECT

      [physical_memory_in_bytes]/1048576 AS [RAM (MB)]

FROM  [sys].[dm_os_sys_info] )

Set @MAX = ((@RAM / 4) * 3)
Set @MIN = ((@RAM / 4) * 1)

if @Mode=0
begin
      exec SP_Configure 'min server memory', 1
      RECONFIGURE
      exec SP_Configure 'max server memory', 100
      RECONFIGURE
end
else
if @Mode = 1
begin
      exec SP_Configure 'max server memory', @MAX
      RECONFIGURE
      exec SP_Configure 'min server memory', @MIN
      RECONFIGURE
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Go for a change in the 'max server memory' setting. If you need more help, read the post *[Used memory not freed up after a SQL BULK insert / BCP export](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21319)*.

Comment: i don't want restart sql server!